# Unable to indentify step definitions of feature file in intelij cucumber project

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have cucumber project in intelij , am able to run the feature file without any issues , but my steps are not navigating me to step definition methods. I added cucumber for java plugin still no luck.

java 11
cucumber for plugin.
cucumber-java of 6.9.1 version.[image]

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: any update please ? there is such example , Intelij supports cucumber 6.9.1 version to do control click on steps in feature file which navigate to step definition method ?

Comment: @CrazyCoder : Can you pls help

Comment: facing similar issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217391

Comment: Still waiting for the sample project, see the first comment for the details.